# Android unicode character font color

Tags: android, unicode

I have an application where I use Unicode characters to display an arrow. The arrows all need a specific color.

This is the result in the Android Studio designer:

[image]

This is the result on my phone:

[image]

It works fine in the designer, not on my phone unfortunately. How do I get the purple color at the arrow on my phone?

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView74"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Meer informatie..."
        android:textColor="#5e5e5e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\u25B6"
        android:id="@+id/textView75"
        android:textColor="#6B00E4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

I tested it on someone else's smartphone and on an emulator, it seems to work on both emulator and the other phone. The emulator and phone both have one of the newest Android versions, the phone where it's not working only has 4.2.2. Can it be something that has to do with te version of Android?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: And your markup for the layout file.

Comment: Done. It's just regular XML.

Comment: @Helix then post please

Answer (score 0):

Try `textView75.setText(Html.fromHtml("\u25B6"));`